# Is it possible to set specific _CFLAGS, _LDADD etc. variables for all programs in a _PROGRAMS variable?

Tags: c, autotools, automake

I'm developing a shared library which ships with test suites, all written in C.

I have a separate makefile which is included by the main Makefile.am, specifically for the tests, which looks similar to this:

```
TESTS = %reldir%/foo\
    %reldir%/bar\
    # etc.
    
check_PROGRAMS = $(TESTS)
LDADD = $(top_builddir)/src/libmylib.la
```

Each test listed in `TESTS` is a .c program that links against the LDADD library, but this linkage is only required for the test programs. Similarly, there are CFLAGS I want to pass for the test programs, but not the library itself, such as `-O0 -g --coverage` and the like.

Since my `TESTS`/`check_PROGRAMS` lists are getting longer the more tests I add, I'd prefer to avoid using per-program `tests_foo_CFLAGS = ...` or `tests_foo_LDADD = ...` assignments, as they're all going to be identical - link against the library, add debug symbols, build for `gcov`, and so on.

Is it possible to just declare these variables for all targets in `TESTS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to just declare these variables for all targets in TESTS?

Not as such.  Automake provides for flag-bearing variables expressing default flags and for variables expressing target-specific flags, but there is no built in way to specify flags that apply to a designated subset of targets.  Nevertheless, there are ways to exercise the available features to get at least close to what you want.

One way is to set up for recursive building via `SUBDIRS` and multiple `Makefile.am` files.  With such a setup, you should be able to have separate default flags of each category for each `Makefile.am`.

But from the wording and the details of the code snippet in the question, I take it that you are using `Automake`'s `include` directive to build a single makefile, and within that makefile you want to express flags that apply to all the test targets, but not any other targets.  Here are some ways to approach that:

1. define all the wanted flags in an ordinary `make` variable, and interpolate them into test-specific variables.  Example:

   ```
   tests_cflags = -O0 -g --coverage
   # ...
   tests_foo_CFLAGS = $(tests_cflags)
   tests_bar_CFLAGS = $(tests_cflags)
   tests_baz_CFLAGS = $(tests_cflags)
   ```

   Although that does not overcome the need for target-specific variables for each test target, it does allow you to manage the actual flags all in one place instead of separately for each test.
2. Flip the script.  Supposing that you have a much higher number of tests than you have other compiled targets, set up the default flags to serve the tests, and, where necessary, override them with target-specific flags for the other targets.  Most of the Automake defaults are conveyed via variables with the `AM_` prefix (`LDADD` is an exception), so that might look something like this:

   ```
   LDADD = $(top_builddir)/src/libmylib.la
   AM_CFLAGS = -O0 -g --coverage
   # ...
   # no tests_foo_CFLAGS, etc.
   # ...
   libmylib_la_CFLAGS = ...
   ```

   Note that the value of the target-specific variables (`libmylib_la_CFLAGS` in this case) can be empty if you just want to suppress the default flags instead of replacing them with different ones.

Either way, you probably want to be familiar with [Automake's flag-variable ordering rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Flag-Variables-Ordering.html).

Comment: Cheers for the answer. Of course, it only occurred to me today that, if I want to run a debugger over my tests, I'd need to have debugging symbols enabled for the library code as well - but that might mean setting up the tests with the .c files as SOURCES instead of the dynamic library with LDADD.

Comment: @MarcusHarrison, yes, for use with a debugger, you probably want to build the library with debug symbols and no optimization (which doesn't change the answer to the question as posed).  But I don't think that's relevant to whether you need `*_SOURCES` variables for the test targets, or whether you can or should use `LDADD` to specify the library dependency.  If each `tests/foo` target is built from `tests/foo.c` alone (plus linking the library) then you do not need `SOURCES` variables for them.  If you want all of them to link the lib then `LDADD` is a fine way to achieve that.

Comment: If you want to build all the sources with the same flags, then `AM_CFLAGS` & co. are still your friends.

Comment: I was suggesting somehow including the .c files of the library in the build process for the tests, so that the library itself wouldn't need to be linked against, and therefore wouldn't need to be built for debugging. It's outside the scope of the question though.

Comment: Oh, I see @MarcusHarrison.  Yes, it is possible to do that, but it's not the way I would go about it myself. Good luck.